# Install a program rpm (iperf) only valid within that folder ( non /usr/bin)

Tags: makefile, fedora, rpm, iperf

I have a program (iperf 2.0.5) in Fedora Linux. I want to run another package of the same newer version of the program (iperf 3.0.3) only restricted / executable local to that folder.

So the default iperf on my PC would be 2.0.5 , but if i want to use iperf 3.0.3 in a designated folder ( similar to what we do in windows ) . We have two execuatble in two different folders and on our preference we run the executable from the folder loaction.

I did download the package from RPM resoure iperf, and it shows the exact specs.

What i have already tried.

./Configure;make;make install iperf # Did not work.

rpm --prefix=/root/Iperf3.0.3/ iperf3.0.0*.rpm. # Indicating that cannot use prefix for package that is already installed.

yum install iperf out of the question because it will make it the default executable.

Thanks
Bharat C P

Comment: You *might* be able to use `rpm --prefix=.... -i iperf3.0.0*.rpm` but I don't know if that will work (and to some extent it depends on whether those packages relocatable I think). What didn't work about compiling it manually?

Comment: Etan,                                                                                                                                          I am experiencing the following errors.                                                                                       [root@dhcp IPERF]# rpm --prefix=/root/iperf 3.0.3/ iperf3-3.0-0.3.b4.fc19.x86_64*.rpm 
rpm: --prefix may only be used when installing new packages, i want to keep both the packages, can you let me know how we can do that.

Comment: You missed the `-i` flag I used in my command. Without it you aren't telling rpm to do anything.

Comment: Etan, i took your suggestion and i am getting a non relocatble error.[root@dhcp-v36-062 iperf3]# rpm -i --prefix=/root/iperf3/ iperf3-3.0-0.3.b4.fc19.x86_64*.rpm 
rpm: --prefix may only be used when installing new packages
warning: iperf3-3.0-0.3.b4.fc19.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fb4b18e6: NOKEY
error: package iperf3 is not relocatable

Comment: Like I said then. So we are back to what didn't work compiling it manually?

Comment: You could consider creating a `chroot` environment or even a Docker container (though the latter might affect your `iperf` measurements)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `--prefix` for a rpm package if the package is relocatable.

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rpm-relocatable-packages/) you can find more information on how to determine if a package is relocatable.

However when you're installing code from source, you usually can specify `--prefix`:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/iperf && make && make install
```